# MultiIndexed pandas dataframe thinks input is unique

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I don't know why but whenever I try to multiIndex a dataframe read in from a csv or excel file it doesn't index properly. The dataframe prints with the 'Assets' labels treated as sections but the dates are incorrectly repeated. However when I do '''print(df.index)''' it still shows the 'Assets' as repeated values. What do I do?

```
[In] df = pd.read_csv(r'\\####\Redir_Mydocs$\Violet.McCabe\My Documents\Troubleshooting.csv',
                 usecols=[0, 1, 2, 4, 5])


df.set_index(['Assets', 'Date'], inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
print(df)
print(df.index)

[Out]
                         Time  Pressure  Running
Assets         Date                              
BH_Swing Frame 7/18/2020    11         1        1
               7/18/2020    12         1        1
               7/18/2020    13         1        1
              ...
Test           7/18/2020    11         1        1
tester         7/18/2020    11         1        1
               7/18/2020    12         1        1
               7/18/2020    13         1        1
               ...
MultiIndex([('BH_Swing Frame', '7/18/2020'),
            ('BH_Swing Frame', '7/18/2020'),
           ...
            (          'Test', '7/18/2020'),
            (        'tester', '7/18/2020'),
            (        'tester', '7/18/2020'),
            ...],
           names=['Assets', 'Date'])
```

EDIT: Here is how it looks in the CSV file:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eArbU.png

Comment: show input as it is in csv file

Comment: Just added a link!